# Prisma Ionic & Sqlite

Tags: prisma, ionic-native

I am working on a mobile app with ionic that requires a localdb

I am trying to use an ORM If possible.

Can I use Prisma or any ORM with Ionic sqlite localdb, if no, can I use any other ORM?

Comment: Yes you can connect with your local DB (SQLite) using Prisma, follow the docs. https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/sqlite

Comment: I am talking about a mobile offline SQLite, are you sure that's gonna work?

Comment: It should work, did you tried using it?

Comment: @NurulSundarani - I'm curious what the `file://` URL would be for the DB in that case.  I think the issue isn't Prima's support for SQLite, but rather the ability to reference a SQLite file path on the mobile platform when defining the schema.

Comment: @N.younes have you managed to get this working?